# pyqtdeploy issue with how to proceed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I'm trying to be able to deploy a project that I made with pyqt5 using pyqtdeploy, I read the whole documentation, which sucks (sorry for the language), I even read the 1.3.2 version, and I still don't know how to make it work. I installed all the packages (using pip and the downloadable files for the demo) and run the setup, but I don't see the executable pyqtdeploy mentinned in the documentation, and the build-demo.py does not work.

I'm on Windows by the way,

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but can sort of one since it "solve" the problem

OK I took a look at the whole code and to add to the fact that there are not the executable in it (the one mentioned in the documentation), all the imports are incorrect, and we have to either rename all the files or modify the import, I think that I'm just going to change and stick with pyinstaller, even if we can only do .exe.

However if someone have figured out how to make it work, I would like to know

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to create a github repo containing a tutorial to create a simple PyQt5 cross-platform app. The main toold used in the repo is [pyqtdeploy](https://pypi.org/project/pyqtdeploy/).

Here is the link to the Github repo: https://github.com/achille-martin/pyqt-crom.

At the moment I can create a VM inside of Windows to setup an Ubuntu machine and generate an Android app from a simple PyQt5 script.